# KinFu for 3D SLAM and navigation

Tags: slam, navigation, mapping, ros-kinetic, rtabmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!
Besides trying out RTABMap and RGBDSlam packages I am also interested in testing KinFu for 3D mapping and robot navigation.
My objective is to do 3D mapping and navigation on distributed ROS system with Raspberry Pi 3 on the robot sending raw images over WiFi to a workstation (Intel Core i5 with GeForce GTX 960) from where I'll be able to visualize and send commands to RPi3 to control the robot.

Can someone recommend me what would be the most adequate to date way of integrating KinFu with ROS navigation stack for mentioned application?

Additionally, are there any other options available for this application?

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with ROS Kinetic.

Thank you in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/287835/kinfu-for-3d-slam-and-navigation/) by [Dox](https://answers.ros.org/users/34329/dox/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2018-04-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't think you can just "test" KinFu for that purpose, it is much more work. So I did it and I can share with you experimental code, but even an experienced programmer would need several days to get it working.
What I can offer you:

- Old KinFu Wrapper: the processing is much more concurred. The original PCL-Code is more a prove of concept, very serial and the GPU is idle most of the time
- Projection an occupancy grid on the ground on the GPU and copy the results into the Host memory. Originally, KinFu approximates just the TSDF by a voxel grid (stored on the device memory)
- the approach uses Kinfu large scale, the local map is copied into a dynamic growing global map
- finding the ground  (plane coefficients, RANSAC)
- interface which is tested/used with the navigation stack

What is missing:

- rectification of the map
- including odometry of the rebot wheels (It really have to be done)
- Kalman filter or similar
- adjust to your robot
- wlan optimization, due to the data traffic
- solving problems due to the lack of loop closure capability of the PCL implementation

See also: https://answers.ros.org/question/142461/pcl-kinfu-in-ros-hydro/

---

Originally posted by [MichaelKorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/905/michaelkorn/) with karma: 1480 on 2018-04-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1